# Get value with regex PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to get the following values from this HTML string using regex:

Values to get 'Ocean View', 'Beachfront', 'Pool', 'Air Conditioning', 'Washer', 'Dryer', 'Close to Shops', 'Parking', 'Fully Furnished', 'Cable/Satellite TV', 'Internet Connection', 'Barbecue', 'Gated Community', 'Close to Schools', 'Fully Equipped', 'Balcony', 'Security', 'Fenced', 'Private Garden':

HTML string

```
<div class='list2'>
Distance to Beach: <span class='detail'>One block</span><br />
Ocean View: <span class='detail'>no</span><br />
Beachfront: <span class='detail'>no</span><br />
Pool: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Air Conditioning: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Washer: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Dryer: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Close to Shops: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Parking: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Fully Furnished: <span class='detail'>yes</span>
</div>
    <div class='list2'>
Cable/Satellite TV: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Internet Connection: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Barbecue: <span class='detail'>no</span><br />
Gated Community: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Close to Schools: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Linens Provided: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Fully Equipped: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Balcony: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Security: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Fenced: <span class='detail'>yes</span><br />
Private Garden: <span class='detail'>no</span>
</div>
```

I have tried the following but it is returning this array

```
$features_tax = "/(.*?): <span class='detail'>yes<\/span>/";
    preg_match_all($features_tax, $web, $web_list);
```

returns:

```
array (size=16)
  0 => string '<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html lang='en'> <head> <meta charset='UTF-8' /><base href='http://www.alliancecostarica.com/' />  <link href='./files/acr.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./files/gallery.css' />      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./files/elastislide.css' /> <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' /> <title></title> <meta name='description' content='' />  <meta name='keywords' content='' /> </head> <body> <div class='... (length=5252)
  1 => string '<br /> Air Conditioning' (length=23)
  2 => string '<br /> Washer' (length=13)
  3 => string '<br /> Dryer' (length=12)
  4 => string '<br /> Close to Shops' (length=21)
  5 => string '<br /> Parking' (length=14)
  6 => string '<br /> Fully Furnished' (length=22)
  7 => string ' </div>  <div class='list2'> Cable/Satellite TV' (length=47)
  8 => string '<br /> Internet Connection' (length=26)
  9 => string '<br /> Barbecue: <span class='detail'>no</span><br /> Gated Community' (length=69)
  10 => string '<br /> Close to Schools' (length=23)
  11 => string '<br /> Linens Provided' (length=22)
  12 => string '<br /> Fully Equipped' (length=21)
  13 => string '<br /> Balcony' (length=14)
  14 => string '<br /> Security' (length=15)
  15 => string '<br /> Fenced' (length=13)
```

The issue are at index 7 and 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always a `<br />` tag in front of the word you can use this pattern:

```php
$pattern = "> (.*?): <span class='detail'>(?:One block|yes|no)<\/span>/";
```

This pattern also includes the different values inside the `<span>` tag in your example.

Comment: Awesome. The Cable/Satellite TV still comes back with a html tag `' <div class='list2'> Cable/Satellite TV'`. Do you know why and how to avoid it?

Comment: Could also explain how this is read `(?:One block|yes|no)`. What does the One block means? Thanks

Comment: This block matches the possible values inside the `<span></span>` tag in the HTML example you have posted above.

Comment: Regarding your first comment about "Cable/Satellite TV". 1. No I don't know why! 2. I've modified my answer and removed the slash `/` at the beginning of the pattern, that it should now also match the "Cable/Satellite TV" section.